# ffmpeg how to show each frame for 1 second?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video, recorded at 7 fps. It's 17 seconds long and has 122 frames.
I want to keep all frames but show them 1 per second, I want the same video to last 122 seconds. I don't want to lose information, but I also don't want the file size to increase.
How can I do that? All the ffmpeg options I see change the frame rate but keep the duration or create/drop frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to slow down your video without reincoding your video to (possibly) keep the file size. You must strip the timestamps by exporting the video to a raw bitstream format:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -map 0:v -c:v copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb raw.h264
```

and than remux it with:

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -r 1 -i raw.h264 -c:v copy output.mp4
```

-r 1 sets the framerate to 1.